# Make requests to third-party api from Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, youtube-api, parse-cloud-code

I need to do some requests every x period of time to YouTube v3 Api and then process this data and store it in Parse.com database.

Can i do this with Cloud Code (Jobs) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with the `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` method ([documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-advanced)).

Here is an example from the Parse documentation. This itself is failry simple but the mentioned documentation has more info about how to set parameters, request headers etc.

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'http://www.parse.com/'
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
  // success
  console.log(httpResponse.text);
},function(httpResponse) {
  // error
  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! Your answer is very helpful for me. Is the good idea make constantly requests to Youtube Api from Cloud Code, something like polling ? For my app i need to do around 1000 requests every 60 min.

Comment: The best option is to use Cloud Code Background jobs for this. You can schedule them and they can run for 15 minutes. Is it a good idea to poll the data? Maybe, it depends on the limits YouTube put in place for the API, the nature of the data you're pulling (frequently changing vs. less frequent) and of course how you want to use the data. Also keep the Cloud Code limitations in mind which should be documented under "Resource Limits". Give it a shot and see if it performs the way you need it I would say.